# Purpose of the binary-all architecture folder folder on debian repositories?

Tags: debian, apt, architecture

Which is the purpose of the `binary-all` architecture folder on debian repositories?

Answer (score 1):

From [the Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Architecture):

> Depending on context and the control file used, the Architecture field
>   can include the following sets of values:
>
> - A unique single word identifying a Debian machine architecture as described in [Architecture specification strings, Section 11.1](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-customized-programs.html#s-arch-spec).
> - An architecture wildcard identifying a set of Debian machine architectures, see [Architecture wildcards, Section 11.1.1](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-customized-programs.html#s-arch-wildcard-spec). `any`
>     matches all Debian machine architectures and is the most frequently
>     used.
> - `all`, which indicates an architecture-independent package.
> - `source`, which indicates a source package.

And from [the Packaging Best Practices](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/best-pkging-practices.html#bpp-archindepdata):

> #### 6.7.5. Architecture-independent data
>
> It is not uncommon to have a large amount of architecture-independent
>   data packaged with a program. For example, audio files, a collection
>   of icons, wallpaper patterns, or other graphic files. If the size of
>   this data is negligible compared to the size of the rest of the
>   package, it's probably best to keep it all in a single package.
>
> However, if the size of the data is considerable, consider splitting
>   it out into a separate, architecture-independent package (_all.deb).
>   By doing this, you avoid needless duplication of the same data into
>   eleven or more .debs, one per each architecture. While this adds some
>   extra overhead into the Packages files, it saves a lot of disk space
>   on Debian mirrors. Separating out architecture-independent data also
>   reduces processing time of lintian (see Section A.2, “Package lint
>   tools”) when run over the entire Debian archive.

So, typically the `binary-all` packages are data files, or executables which are architecture independent (like scripts). By keeping these separate, the load on the repositories is reduced.

Comment: But the `binary-all` folder only contains the `Packages` files and no packages. That `Packages` files aren't read by amd64. The `binary-amd64/Packages`files include all `binary-all` packages repeated. So I suppose, that since the existence of `debian/pool` folder, the `binary-all` folder is useless.

Comment: @ncomputers.org it looks like you're right: [it might be a mistake](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/286/Setting_up_your_own_APT_repository_with_upload_support#comment_14) to have `binary-all`.